# insert data based on existing data

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, unique-constraint

I have a table which has column like (CId, Source). Value for source can be (0,1,2,3). Now Table should have only two records for a CId.

1. CId = 'X' and Source = 0
2. CId = 'X' and Source = 1 (can be 2 or 3 as well)

After this, if any other records comes (X,2) (X,3) should not be inserted.

Keeping in mind the above constraints, I want to insert records into the table from a source file.
I am using SSIS package to load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a computed `bit` column that is `0` or `1` depending on the value in `Source` and add a unique constraint on the computed column and `CId`.

```
create table YourTable
(
  CId char(1) not null,
  Source int not null,
  SourceBit as cast(Source as bit),
  unique (CId, SourceBit)
)
```